# Cylinder Parallel Transport

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

In general the parallel transport of a certain vector between two points p and q in a given surface may change depending on the curve used to go from p to q. However, in a cylinder the parallel transport depends of a certain vector depends only on the points p and q being independent of the chosen curve. What is the proof of that property of the cylinder?

Comment: What do you think is the explanation? And does it work on a cone?

Comment: If you need a hint, try looking at the connection coefficients for the cylinder. What do they imply about parallel transport?

Comment: To add a small hint to Ted's comment, are you happy with the corresponding statement in the Euclidean plane?